# Firebase Cloud Database Rules - how to retrieve data only where the user id matches a key in the object?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there a way using firebase rules to retrieve all the projects that have a specific "userID" value. I tried reading all the rules and came up with this rule but they do not work: 
I only want to read the documents which matches auth.uid == userID in database.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Allow public read access, but only content owners can write
    match /debtors/{userID}/{documents=**} {

      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == userID;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == userID;;
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following object in collection:

```
{firstname: "Aacis"
relation: "friend"
userID: "7ScK2T0T3SMUR1NJxjiCiRzTnm62"}
```

Fetching stream in flutter with:

```
stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection("debtors")
            .where("userID", isEqualTo: user.uid)
            .snapshots()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set `auth.uid` as document id, and object key named `userID`?

```
Firestore.instance.collection("debtors").doc("7ScK2T0T3SMUR1NJxjiCiRzTnm62").set({
    firstname: "Aacis",
    relation: "friend",
    userID: "7ScK2T0T3SMUR1NJxjiCiRzTnm62"
})
```

If you want to allow only onwer to read access to then you should set `allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == userID;`

If you want to read the documents which matches auth.uid == resource.data.userID then you should set `allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid = resource.data.userID;`

If you want to allow public to read access then you should set `allow read: if true;`

And More, A read rule can be broken into get and list.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // A read rule can be divided into get and list rules
    match /cities/{city} {
      // Applies to single document read requests
      allow get: if <condition>;

      // Applies to queries and collection read requests
      allow list: if <condition>;
    }

    // A write rule can be divided into create, update, and delete rules
    match /cities/{city} {
      // Applies to writes to nonexistent documents
      allow create: if <condition>;

      // Applies to writes to existing documents
      allow update: if <condition>;

      // Applies to delete operations
      allow delete: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource

## Updated

A `userID` in the following code means the document id is `auth.uid`, and allow only onwer to read access.

```
    match /debtors/{userID}/{documents=**} {

      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == userID;
```

So you don't set `auth.uid` as document id, and the stored value named `userID` in the document match `auth.uid`, you should use `resource.data.userID` and `request.resource.data.userID`.

Please try the following code.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /debtors/{document=**} {

      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userID;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID;
    }
  }
}
```

> The resource variable refers to the requested document, and resource.data is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document. For more information on the resource variable, see the reference documentation.
>
> When writing data, you may want to compare incoming data to existing data. In this case, if your ruleset allows the pending write, the request.resource variable contains the future state of the document. For update operations that only modify a subset of the document fields, the request.resource variable will contain the pending document state after the operation. You can check the field values in request.resource to prevent unwanted or inconsistent data updates:

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#resource

Comment: I did not set auth.uid as document id, coz I need multiple documents.. I only set userID: as auth.uid